# List iterator returns last rows only

Tags: java, list, collections, iterator

```
Iterator<Account> entitiesItr = entities.iterator();
List<AccountSync> accountsList = new ArrayList<AccountSync>();
AccountSync accountsync = new AccountSync();
while (entitiesItr.hasNext()) {
    Account account = (Account) entitiesItr.next();
    accountsync.setAccountName(account.getName());
    accountsList.add(accountsync);
    System.out.println("1st-name->"+account.getName());
}

Iterator<AccountSync> it = accountsList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    AccountSync accountSync2 = (AccountSync) it.next();
    System.out.println("2nd-name->"+accountSync2.getAccountName());
        }
```

output:

```
1st-name->Sun
1st-name->Oracle
1st-name->google
...
1st-name->Yahoo



2nd-name->Yahoo
2nd-name->Yahoo
2nd-name->Yahoo
2nd-name->Yahoo
....50 times
```

2nd-name-> prints only last rows 50 times, while 1st-name-> it prints all 50 rows. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the first loop keep overwriting the same `AccountSync`.
Try this way:

```
AccountSync accountsync;
while (entitiesItr.hasNext()) {
    accountsync = new AccountSync();
    Account account = (Account) entitiesItr.next();
    accountsync.setAccountName(account.getName());
    accountsList.add(accountsync);
    System.out.println("1st-name->"+account.getName());
}
```

in that case, each entity will have its own `AccountSync` instance properly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to move

```
AccountSync accountsync = new AccountSync();
```

to inside of your while loop otherwise you are using the same one and simply updating it.